# What's the difference between Angular 1.x Controller and Angular 2 Component?

Tags: angular

What's the difference between Angular 1.x Controller and Angular 2 Component?  Will a Controller in Angular 1.x still work in Angular 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Angular v2 (now just called "Angular") is completely different from Angular v1 (now called "AngularJS"). You cannot use AngularJS controllers in an Angular application.

The exceptions to this is if you are using the ngUpgrade feature, which is meant to help you migrate an appliction from v1 to v2+.

Angular components are not just AngularJS controllers with a different name. They work very differently. See the pictures below.

Since Angular is so different, you may want to consider working through the Angular tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial

Or an Angular training course such as this one: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update

[image]

[image]

Comment: how are they different?  is it the same thing just a new name?

Comment: No. Conceptually Angular is VERY different from AngularJS. There are some similarities, such as the binding. Pretty much everything else is different. See pictures above.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1(AngularJS) is very different to Angular 2(Angular). 
AngularJS used controllers to build out the app. Controllers are objects and are not compatible with Angular.

Angular used components to build out the app. Components are basically directive but must always have a template.

More on Angular Components: https://angular.io/api/core/Component